# For an odd number n, let n!! be the product: n(n − 2)(n − 4)...1. Express n!! in terms of factorials and exponentials

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Our teacher also wants us to use Stirling's approximation in order to figure out how n!! grows asymptotically. Confused on how to go about this

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial.

Comment: Strongly recommend just writing out the examples of $n = 1, 3, 5$ to see what is going on.  This might inform what you could try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write $n=2k+1$, to make the assumption that $n$ is odd easier to work with.

$$\begin{align*}
n!! &= (2k+1)(2k-1)(2k-3)\dots 3\cdot 1 = \frac{(2k+1)2k(2k-1)(2k-2)(2k-3)\dots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{2k(2k-2)(2k-4)\dots 2}\\
&= \frac{(2k+1)!}{2k\cdot 2(k-1)\cdot 2(k-2)\dots 2\cdot 1}=
\frac{(2k+1)!}{2^k k!} \\
&= \frac{n!}{2^{(n-1)/2}\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)!}
\end{align*}$$

The trick is to multiply numerator and denominator by the missing factors to make a factor appear. The missing factors, in turn, are all even, so you can factor out the $2$'s...

Answer (score 0):

For any even number $2n$ we may have a product $P = 2n\cdot2(n-1)\cdot2(n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot2$, from this we may factor out our $2$s and we get $P = 2^n\cdot n!$

Now now we would like to show that $(2n-1)!! < P < (2n+1)!!$, this is easily done as each term in the product can be mapped to a larger term in the product above after it. For example if $2n-k$ is a term in $(2n-1)!!$ then $(2n-k+1$) is a term $P$'s product representation, and then $(2n-k+2)$ is a term in $(2n+1)!!$.

Now we have shown that $k!!$ (for odd $k$) has the same growth as $2^{\left(\frac k2\right)}\cdot \left(\frac k2!\right)$ (for even $k$), and now we may use sterling's approximation for the factorial function and we should be good.